# Problem is in renaming the columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to give the column names to call them in the rest of the function, but I don't know why I have this problem. Even though it looks fine, can someone help me solve this problem in pandas?

This the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Chemin du fichier CSV
file_path_asset = 'C://Users//AZLBAIBI//Desktop//Ex2 TP//Asset.csv'

# Lire le fichier CSV dans un DataFrame
data =pd.read_csv(file_path_asset, skiprows=0 ,delimiter=',')

# Renommer les colonnes 
data.columns = ["asset_id", "asset_reference", "asset_type", "product_warranty_start_date", "product_warranty_end_date"]


print(data) #### The problem is in renaming the columns. I don't know how to fix this issue
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMN9i.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAqmF.png)

Comment: can you open your CSV file and provide the first three lines of the file as text?

Comment: Please quote textual output instead of images of it

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without a sample of the csv,
but you should figure out what are the column names when you load from the csv. Then, I prefer to create a dictionary translating between the old column names and the new column names you want to rename to.
Then use pd.DataFrame.rename:

assuming the columns names after loading the csv are

```
['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4', 'col5']
```

and the new names are

```
["asset_id", "asset_reference", "asset_type", "product_warranty_start_date", "product_warranty_end_date"]
```

this is how you rename the columns:

```
column_mapper_dict = {
'col1': 'asset_id',
'col2': 'asset_reference',
'col3': 'asset_type',
'col4': 'product_warranty_start_date',
'col5': 'product_warranty_end_date'
}
data = data.rename(columns=column_mapper_dict)
```

Comment: pandas **will** accept the statement `df.columns = ['col1', 'col2']` or whatever as long as the number of columns matches the DF; the columns are renamed in the order as Listed. It is not clear why the OP is having a problem.

Comment: thanks I didn't know that. I edited my answer